# Why is an Nd:YAG laser not useful for holography at $1064$nm?

Tags: laser

Why is an Nd:YAG laser not good for holography when operated at $1064$nm? I've seen papers online that describe it being used for holography but our lecturer said it's not suitable. Part of the problem is I'm not sure what the requirements for holography would be.

Comment: Why don't you ask your lecturer what they meant?

Comment: Well - for one thing it's not visible light...

Comment: Use another device to double the output frequency, though, and you've got 532 nm, which is the green color you see in 90% of photos of holograms. So it certainly is useful for holography, you just can't use the raw 1064 nm output as it is.

Comment: Film is not very sensitive in the IR.

Answer (score 1):

The typical emulsions used for recording holograms (silver halide and dichromated gelatin) aren't very sensitive to 1064nm. I don't doubt it's possible to do use 1064nm given the correct emulsion chemistry, but it becomes increasingly difficult to cause the photochemical reactions necessary to expose the film as you move into the infrared. This is because infrared photons tend to interact with atoms kinetically (causing vibration) rather than photochemically.